# Bad Gateway errors when trying to connect Laravel Homestead to sqlsrv database

Tags: laravel-5, pdo, sqlsrv, php-7.1

I have been using Laravel v5 for a little while now, connecting to a homestead/vagrant virtual machine and integrating into a local MySQL database.  However, I now need to connect remotely to a MSSQL database on my network via the same virtual machine.

Originally I was receiving `driver not found` errors when trying to use the `sqlsrv` connection, but I overcome that by installing the `php7.1-sybase` package.  I can now confirm that `php -m` is indicating that `pdo_dblib` is installed and enabled.

I have setup the connection details in my `.env` file to use a second database connection:

```
DB_CONNECTION_SECOND=sqlsrv
DB_HOST_SECOND=<server>
DB_PORT_SECOND=1433
DB_DATABASE_SECOND=<database>
DB_USERNAME_SECOND=<username>
DB_PASSWORD_SECOND=<password>
```

I can successfully ping the server from my virtual machine.

Within my model, I have specified the `$connection` and `$table` parameters:

```
/**
 * The database name used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $connection = 'sqlsrv';

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = '<tablename>';
```

And in my controller, I am simply trying to return a single record back using a where claus:

```
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{



    $employees = Employee::where( 'LastName', '=', 'Bloggs' )->get();



    return $employees;



}
```

However, any connection that I try and make results in a `502 Bad Gateway` error. I have also tried connecting to different databases on the network but I still get the same error.

Comment: Did you configure your `*_SECOND` env variables in config/database.php ?

Comment: My `database.php` file already contained a `sqlsrv` entry so I didn't make any changes to this file at all.  Have I overlooked something?

Comment: There will be `env('DB_DATABASE', 'somedefaultvalue')` you need to change this to reflect your env variables. Like `env('DB_DATABASE_SECOND', 'somedefaultvalue')`

Comment: Thanks @Mike, however I now receive a `Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (severity 9)` error.  Not sure if this is related or I need to start a new thread.

Comment: Seems like the bad gateway is fixed are you sure your database is up and you are using the right ports / adresses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have added new .env variables.
Make sure you use those `*_SECOND` variables in your config/database.php

There probably already is a part in database.php like `env('DB_DATABASE', 'somedefaultvalue')` change it to `env('DB_DATABASE_SECOND', 'somedefaultvalue')` for all your added variables.

Comment: Your suggestion was correct and definitely solved my bad gateway error so thankyou.  The other error I mentioned was fixed by altering `/etc/freetds/freetds.conf` file to adjust the tds version to version 8.0.